# How to start an activity in BackgroundTask only after verifing that the username and password is correct?

Tags: java, php, android-activity, android-asynctask, phpmyadmin

I am trying to start an activity "Display" which is supposed to start only after the user is authenticated (the usernames and passwords are stored in phpmyadmin database)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PatLogin extends Activity {

    EditText a,b;
    String login_name,login_pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pat_login);

    }

    public void patbuttonClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.patlogin) {
            a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpusername);
            b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFppassword);
            login_name = a.getText().toString();
            login_pass = b.getText().toString();


            String method = "login";
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
            backgroundTask.execute(method,login_name,login_pass);

            //If possible I would like to call the "Display" activity from here but only when the correct username and password is entered. 
           //If it's not possible to call from here then I would like to know how to call "Display" activity from "BackgrounTask.java".





        }

    }
}
```

The BackgroundTask.java is used to authenticate the user (check if the username and password match) through the phpmyadmin database.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx =ctx;
    }
    int flag=0;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/mobidoc/login.php";
        String method = params[0];

            if(method.equals("login"))
        {
            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
            //When I use the following 2 lines of code, It calls the Display activity even if the wrong password is entered. I need a certain condition to be applied.
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, Display.class);
            ctx.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }


}
```

So what I want to do is call an activity named "Display". This activity should be called only when the correct username and password is entered.

I am attaching the php file too, just for reference.

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$username = $_POST["login_name"];
$password = $_POST["login_pass"];
$password = md5($password);
$sql_query = "select name from pat_info where username like '$username' and password like '$password';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$name = $row["name"];
echo "Login Success... Welcome ".$name;}

else{
echo "Login Failed...Try Again.";
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you should "go ahead and start the activity, in any case." But the first order-of-business for that activity, should be for ***it*** to determine whether it is allowed to proceed any further. *(To do this, it consults the background task, and waits for a response.)* The activity terminates if it is not authorized, and proceeds with the display if it is. The code which launches the activity has no reason to care how things turned out . . .

Comment: And how should I go about doing that. I'm totally new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got the solution to it. I had to compare the echo of the php file and compare it with "res" which stores the value of "result". The modified "BackgroundTask.java" is below:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;
    String res;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx =ctx;
    }
    int flag=0;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/mobidoc/login.php";
        String method = params[0];

            if(method.equals("login"))
        {
            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                //I stored the response in the following String variable (res)
                res = response;
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(res.equals("Login Failed...Try Again."))
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();

        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, Display.class);
            ctx.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }


}
```